# External API data to google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to created a polygon on google maps using data from an external API  http://geokey.org.uk/docs/web/project-response.html

the API response gives the following:

```
{
"id": 28,
"name": "Local spots",
"description": "",
"isprivate": true,
"status": "active",
"created_at": "2014-09-15T09:40:01.747Z",
"geographic_extent": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [-0.508, 51.682],
            [-0.53, 51.327],
            [0.225, 51.323],
            [0.167, 51.667],
            [-0.508, 51.682]
        ]
    ]
},
```

How do i extract geographic_extent - coordinates and render them as polygon on google map? - I understand it should be an AJAX but get get would return a whole array?

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Script for generaing the map
        var map;

```
    function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the 'geographic_extent' node from the ajax response received you can use the JSON.parse function. e.g.;

```
var result = JSON.parse('{"id": 28,"name": "Local spots","description": "","isprivate": true,"status": "active","created_at": "2014-09-15T09:40:01.747Z","geographic_extent": {"type": "Polygon",    "coordinates": [[[-0.508, 51.682],[-0.53, 51.327],[0.225, 51.323],[0.167, 51.667],[-0.508, 51.682]]]}');
```

now you can get

```
-0.508,51.682,-0.53,51.327,0.225,51.323,0.167,51.667,-0.508,51.682
```

with

```
result.geographic_extent.coordinates
```

For plotting it as a polygon, use the following code

```
var triangleCoords = [
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
          {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
          {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
        ];


        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: triangleCoords,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

Notice the way triangleCoords are defined, its an array of lat, lng object. If you want to plot the polygon received from your ajax request you will need to put it in similar array of lat, lng objects.

[http://jsbin.com/kupeyofemo/edit?html,output](http://jsbin.com/domegefama/1/edit?html,output)